# How to sanitize a file with ESAPI?

Tags: java, spring, file, esapi

I am currently trying to resolve the following vulnerability:
`Improper Neutralization of Input During Web Page Generation ('Cross-site Scripting')`

I have searched many posts and documentation of all kinds and in all situations it is only explained how to solve it in cases where you have a front.

In my case it is only a microservice that communicates with other microservices, and the only validation I do is of the file name. But not the content of the file. Since it is a microservice in charge of uploading an infinity of files of all kinds to a repository.

```
@PostMapping("uploadFile")
    public ResponseEntity<String> uploadDatos(@RequestParam MultipartFile file,
            @RequestParam(required = false) String directory)
    {

        File fileCast= service.multipartfileToFile(file);

        if (directory == null)
            return new ResponseEntity<String>(service.uploadFile(fileCast, ""), HttpStatus.OK);
        else
            return new ResponseEntity<String>(service.uploadFile(fileCast, directory), HttpStatus.OK);

    }
```

The method of cast multipart file to file.

```
public File multipartfileToFile(MultipartFile file) {


        String filename = FilenameUtils.normalize(file.getOriginalFilename());
        // This utils is mine for extra validation
        if (Utils.isValidFilename(filename)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        File convFile = new File(filename);
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(convFile);
            fos.write(file.getBytes());
            fos.close();
        }
        .... // Catch clauses...
        return convFile;
    }
```

And honestly I don't know what to do to validate the file, it's probably silly

Comment: have you tried like this @CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*")

Comment: @GaneshGudghe No, but what does exatcly

Comment: Sanitizing a file is different from file type detection.  What exactly are you trying to do, please update your question with one, the other, or both.

Comment: Also, the vulnerability detail you provided talks about XSS which is too, a separate topic.

Comment: In your authentication with the other services, are you passing a (JWT, OAuth etc) token to your clients and updating them on each request?